# Ajax DELETE redirects even if prevented

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to delete row from database with DELETE method and using AJAX in my Laravel 5.2 project. Everything is working, picture is deleted from server and the row is deleted from database but after deleting it redirects to JSON response.

My controller's action:

```
public function deletePhoto(Photo $photo)
{
    if ($photo->delete()) {
        unlink('files/' . $photo->filename);
        unlink('files/thumbs/' . $photo->filename);

        return response()->json(['result' => 0]);
    }

    return response()->json(['result' => 1]);
}
```

It works this way while adding photos (it adds but doesn't redirect).

Here is my ajax code:

```
$('#deleteForm').submit(function(e) {
        var currentElement = $(this);
        var formUrl = $(this).attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: formUrl,
            data: {_method: 'delete', _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'},
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.result == 0) {
                    currentElement.parent().fadeOut(400, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('Wystąpił błąd podczas usuwania zdjęcia! Proszę spróbować ponownie!');
                }

            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

I tried many changes (from laracast and stackoverflow) with method, token and data but nothing worked.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I also had `dataType: 'json'` and cache, contentType, processData set to false but nothing worked.

Comment: What do you mean by it redirects to JSON response? The page is redirecting after the request is made?

Comment: Exactly, it should stay at deleting page but it redirects to blank page with JSON result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a prevent default to your submit event. The page is redirecting because you're initiating a submit event.

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Change submit event to:

```
$("#form-submit-button").click(function(e){

});
```

Comment: Does it still redirect?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: Try adding an ID to the submit button being clicked and then add a click event on that ID. Then add preventDefault. Does that work?

Comment: Should I remove preventDefault from form submit function?

Comment: Delete the form submit event and replace it with a click event on the button being clicked.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven't though this would work. Of course it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#deleteForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var currentElement = $(this);
    var formUrl = $(this).attr('action');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: formUrl,
        data: {_method: 'delete', _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'},
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.result == 0) {
                currentElement.parent().fadeOut(400, function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            } else {
                alert('Wystąpił błąd podczas usuwania zdjęcia! Proszę spróbować ponownie!');
            }

        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

you need to add [preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent the page from redirecting

Comment: Thanks for answer but the one above is the same :) Unfortunately, it's not working for me :/

Answer (score 0):

check from console if there is errors in javascript code to work the e.preventDefault

Comment: I am always checking console but thanks for your help :) @Frisbetarian answer (in comments) worked.